# What's the name for [the other kind of planet] in a binary star system?

Tags: planet, exoplanet, binary-star, terminology

[This XKCD what-if](http://what-if.xkcd.com/150/) talks about rainbows on planets in a binary star system.   It points out that there are two types:

- ***circumbinary*** planets, where the planet orbits far from and around both stars
- ***[the other kind of planet]***, where the planet orbits one of the stars and the other star is distant.

[image]

## What is the proper name for [the other kind of planet] ?

Comment: The term I usually see is "non-circumbinary". I wonder if there is a better term.

Comment: I would have thought "circumstellar", as it orbits a single star and it sounds better than "circumunary".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy "circumstellar" is also used for "circumsystem" objects though which orbit around multiple stars.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about names for the planets, specifically, but the orbits are called [S-type and P-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star#Planets):

- **S-type**: The planet orbits around one star, and the host star has a binary companion (i.e., "the other kind" in the XKCD comic)
- **P-type**: The planet orbits around both stars of the binary

Comment: I propose the name "circumunary planet". It would be usable for both planets in systems like ours and in binary systems. You could refer to "the circumunary planet of Alpha Centauri B in the Alpha Centauri binary star system" for example, and you could also say "Earth is a circumunary planet of the sun in the solar system, a unary star".

Comment: All planets of unary stars would be circumunary by definition, but planets in binary star systems could be either circumunary or circumbinary.

Comment: Also, is it possible there are some objects which are gravitationally bound to a binary system but which technically revolve around neither star?

Comment: @called2voyage:   Objects can be in or in semi-stable orbits around the various Lagrangian points.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to, I'm just not sure how stable they would be

Comment: in a binary system a Lagrange point (L4 or 5) could be stable, around the smaller of the 2 stars, not the larger (obviously).    The star ratio of mass has to be about 25 to 1 though.   http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11389/orbits-in-a-binary-star-system

Comment: @userLTK Thanks, so we do have another type of planet to consider besides circumbinary and circumunary.

Answer (score 2):

Astronomy currently only gives us the names circumbinary (left picture) and Trojan planet (unpictured, planet is around a Lagrange point), but from circumbinary we can extrapolate other names:

- circumunary - revolves around one star
- circumtrinary/circumternary - revolves around a trinary/ternary star system

Technically, there is another term that actually has some use: circumsystem. This is used for objects that revolve around a multiple star system regardless of the number of stars within the system.

Comment: The problem with this nomenclature is you want to distinguish between planets in binary systems and those that are not. I realise that - the "planet Alpha Cen Bb" makes this obvious, but that doesn't help when referring to them as a class.

Comment: @RobJeffries I realize "circumunary planets of binary systems" is a bit of a mouthful, but at least more concise than "planets which orbit only one star of a binary system".

Comment: But not more concise than "s-type exoplanet".

Comment: @RobJeffries True, though I thought strictly speaking those were considered types of orbits not types of planets, so wouldn't that be "exoplanets in s-type orbits" in the strictest sense?